# how to save to two different database table in cakephp at thesame time

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have two tables. the first is the **user table** with the following fields:

```
- id
- username
- password
- email
```

and i have another table called **book_authors** with the following fields:

```
- id
- user_id
- number_of_books
- date
```

the question here is that, how do i save into the **book_authors** table `id and user_id` when i create a new user, i.e I would like the **book_authors** table to be filled automatically when i create a new user.

Comment: And what should be the value goes there?

Comment: i want to save the newly created user's id into the "book_authors" table(that is, the user_id) table when i create a new user.

Answer (score 2):

Automatic insertion is not possible in dependent table.You need to do in this way--

```
if($this->User->save($data)){// when saving user data
  $user_id = $this->User->id; // get last inserted id
    $data['book_authors']['user_id'] = $user_id;
    $data['book_authors']['number_of_books'] = 0;
    $data['book_authors']['date'] = date('Y-m-d');
   $this->BookAuthor->save($data);

}
```

Note:-

1.Automatically only deletion is possible in cakephp by defining dependency is true in model in relationship definition "has one" or etc.

2.I gave an general example, you need to change things accordingly.